# How to run ELF binary file on cygwin

Tags: cygwin, elf

I'm new to cygwin but I am having a bit of a trouble.

I have Linux ELF compiled binary file, and is there a way to lunch it under cygwin a simple way, like windows binary for example .\a.exe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from https://www.cygwin.com/

> Cygwin is not:
>
> a way to run native Linux apps on Windows. You must rebuild your
>   application from source if you want it to run on Windows.

If you want to run a ELF binary you need a VM with Linux inside

Comment: Recent Windows 10 versions support ELF binaries in the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux)